# I have been trying to fetch an API recipepuppy.com and I keep getting this : Syntax Error and 500 Internal server error

Tags: reactjs

I have used recipepuppy api and while fetching the items i'm unable to get the result and i keep on getting this error
the code is

```
search(){
    let {ingredients, dish} = this.state;
    const url =`http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=${ingredients}&q=${dish}`;
    fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log('recipes', json));
}
```

I'm getting this error in console as

```
SearchRecipes.js:17          GET http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=garlic,chicken&q=adobo 500 (Internal Server Error)
search @ SearchRecipes.js:17
onClick @ SearchRecipes.js:49
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:189
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:238
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:291
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:306
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:391
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:416
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:3301
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3310
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:3282
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3327
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3537
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3581
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21729
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:798
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3591
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4311
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4232
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:659
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11077
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21746
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:811
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4211
VM1141:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 91
```

please help me with this

Comment: A 500 error is a problem on the server (API). If this is not an API you have control over, the only thing you can do is notify them of the bug. There's a chance you are not using the API correctly (I don't know for sure), but even so, I would consider any API returning a 500 response to be a bug.

Comment: Congratulation on your first question and welcome to StackOverflow!
As  @BrianThompson said, the problem is not with your code but the API, you can confirm by pasting your API  URL on a browser and opening your browser console to see the 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on your end, this API does not send the body data properly, and concatenates an HTML string onto a JSON response, hence you can't actually parse the response properly. If this isn't your API just contact the owner and let them know.